# Uploading picked image from gallery to parse

Tags: parsing, swift

so I have this code that compiles without errors:

```
    @IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject){
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as NSString]
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
        completion: nil)
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        var user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData)
        user["profilePicture"] = imageFile;
        user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But it skips right over the imagePickerController function and once i pick an image it sends me back to my main viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the delegate to self so you need to have those methods accessible by self.
When they are nested inside of the IBAction they are only visible from within it.

Take the delegate methods and put them outside of the IBAction.

```
@IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject){
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as NSString]
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true,
    completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData)
    user["profilePicture"] = imageFile;
    user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tested it and the "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" delegate method is called after selecting an image.